# Which is better to play though, Digest Mode on Agarest War Zero or the actual game in Agarest War?

Tags: record-of-agarest-war-zero, record-of-agarest-war

I was reading that there is a Digest Mode that you unlock if you access the hard mode in Agarest Generations of War Zero (by either completing the game or by loading in Agarest Generations of War Cleared Saved Game) which allows you to play though all of Agarest Generations of War and always get the True Route.

Now from my reading I know I have to go though this mode in order to defeat the Gods to obtain the titles associated with them but in terms of actually playing though Agarest Generations of War's storyline, which is better, doing it though Digest Mode or having the actual game

I ask mainly referring to the mechanics and story (i.e. story may be shorter or key components missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In digest mode you are playing through all the generations minus "red dot" battles. You will always receive the True ending no matter what choices you make and all the of the bride choices are preset. So this pretty much means that the story will be the same just with less battling. However the game mechanic of choosing your bride and then forming each generation will be lost if they are preset. Since this is a major part of the game and in the game itself there are fully dozens of possibilities of what your 5th gen hero can be like this is a big lose in the mechanics department. So I would say the verdict is if you just want the story go with digest if you want that 5 generation character building get the game.